# Types of mathematical questions?

Tags: philosophy-of-language, language

Are there any other kinds of mathematical questions people ask besides the following?

1. Requests for results
2. Requests for proofs/justification
3. Requests for illustrations or other aids to the intuition
4. Requests for the explanation of a method whose purpose is already understood *How do you . . . ?* questions)
5. Requests for advice on what method to use in a given situation
6. Requests for interpretations (*What does this mean?*, *What does this allow us to do?*, etc.)
7. Requests for physical interpretations and applications
8. Requests to check that some result, proof, illustration/intuition, method, interpretation, etc. is correct
9. Requests to find errors in something thought to be false
10. Requests for alternative methods (*e.g.*, *"Could you give a purely combinatorial proof of . . . ?"*)
11. Requests for the explanation of symbols
12. Requests for the identification of a concept (*e.g.*, *"What have I just calculated?"*)
13. Requests to be told the name of a concept, or for a name to be invented if none yet exists
14. Requests for "reverse engineering" (*e.g.*, *"Can we find an equation that would approximate this?"*, *"What would produce a curve such as this?"*, etc.)
15. Requests for advice on what keywords to use when looking something up
16. Requests for counter-examples

Thanks!

Comment: Not clear. All those types might overlap a lot, and although many are related with mathematics, are not "mathematical questions".

Answer (score 1):

Where is the "theorem-creating" category?!

I'd say that your list is missing concepts that the asker may not even know about:

I'd add "request for generalization". Sometimes a statement can be proven for a particular case and the *asker* may wonder if there is some more general theory underlying the problem, not even asking for a particular concept (I'd argue that this is different than simply being told what the name of the concept is). An example of this would be in number theory; an *asker* may wonder if there is a way to extend the notion of factorization of the integers to a more abstract notion.

Another type of problem that comes up often goes as follows: x thinks [p=>q] (intuitively), he then finds a counter example. x may then ask "is there some *interesting* proposition, say r, such that [p and r => q]?" ('interesting' is added since, clearly, r=q is a solution lol). He wouldn't be asking for a particular thing to be proven nor an specific concept but rather he would be asking for the creation of a theorem.

Theorem creation should be added IMO.

Comment: 'a statement' replaces 'an statement'.